# Clojure: data resulting from parallel computation seems to be significantly slower to access

Tags: concurrency, clojure

I've got a function which concurrently counts the frequencies of certain features in a text file and collates the data. The output of the function is thousands of frequency distributions stored in a persistent map. As a simple example:

```
{"dogs" {"great dane" 2, "poodle" 4}, "cats" {"siamese" 1 "tom" 3}}
```

and the code that would produce this:

```
(defn do-the-thing-1 [lines species_list]
  ;; we know the full list of species beforehand so to avoid thread contention
  ;; for a single resource, make an atom for each species
  (let [resultdump      (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (atom {})) {} species_list)
        line-processor  (fn [line]
                          (fn [] ; return a function that will do the work when invoked
                            (doseq [[species breed] (extract-pairs line)]
                              (swap! ; increase the count for this species-breed pair
                                (resultdump species)
                                update-in [breed] #(+ 1 (or % 0))))))
        pool            (Executors/newFixedThreadPool 4)]
    ;; queue up the tasks
    (doseq [future (.invokeAll pool (map line-processor lines))]
      (.get future))
    (.shutdown pool)
    (deref-vals result)))

(defn deref-vals [species_map]
  (into {} (for [[species fdist] species_map] [species @fdist]))
```

This works fine. The problem is that I need to convert them to probability distributions before I can use them. e.g.

```
{"dogs" {"great dane" 1/3, "poodle" 2/3}, "cats" {"siamese" 1/4, "tom" 3/4}}
```

Here's the function that does that:

```
(defn freq->prob 
  "Converts a frequency distribution into a probability distribution"
  [fdist]
  (let [sum (apply + (vals fdist))]
    (persistent!
      (reduce
        (fn [dist [key val]] (assoc! dist key (/ val sum)))
        (transient fdist)
        (seq fdist)))))
```

Doing this conversion on the fly as the distributions are being consumed by the next step in the processing pipeline gives reasonable speeds, but also a fair amount of redundant conversions as some distributions are used more than once. When I modify my function to perform the conversions in parallel before returning the result, the speed at which latter stages of processing occur drops dramatically.

Here's the modified function:

```
(defn do-the-thing-2 [lines species_list]
  ;; we know the full list of species beforehand so to avoid thread contention
  ;; for a single resource, make an atom for each species
  (let [resultdump      (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (atom {})) {} species_list)
        line-processor  (fn [line]
                          (fn [] ; return a function that will do the work when invoked
                            (doseq [[species breed] (extract-pairs line)]
                              (swap! ; increase the count for this species-breed pair
                                (resultdump species)
                                update-in [breed] #(+ 1 (or % 0))))))
        pool            (Executors/newFixedThreadPool 4)]
    ;; queue up the tasks
    (doseq [future (.invokeAll pool (map line-processor lines))]
      (.get future))

    ;; this is the only bit that has been added
    (doseq [future (.invokeAll pool (map
                                      (fn [fdist_atom]
                                        #(reset! fdist_atom (freq->prob @fdist_atom)))
                                      (vals resultdump)))]
      (.get future))

    (.shutdown pool)
    (deref-vals result)))
```

So yeah, this makes everything afterward about 10x slower than it is when simply calling `freq->prob` upon every access to the resulting map, though the returned data is identical. Can anyone suggest reasons as to why that may be or what I could do about it?

EDIT: I'm now suspecting it has something to do with Clojure's fractions. If I modify the `freq->prob` function to create floats or doubles in stead of fractions, performance is improved when pre-computing the probability distributions as opposed to generating them on-the-fly. Could it be that fractions created in an atom run slower than fractions created outside an atom? I just ran some simple tests that indicate this is not the case, so there's definitely something weird going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I've followed your logic, but your map function here:

```
(map
    (fn [fdist_atom]
        #(reset! fdist_atom (freq->prob @fdist_atom)))
    (vals resultdump))
```

doesn't look right. If you are updating an atom based on its old value, `swap!` is more appropriate than `reset!` for a function applied to the dereferenced value of the atom. This would seem better:

```
(map
    (fn [fdist_atom] (swap! fdist_atom freq->prob))
    (vals resultdump))
```

Comment: There's no need to use transactional features here because no other threads could possibly try to read or alter the value of the atom. Your version would work, sure, but I used `reset!` because I assume it's faster than `swap!`.

Comment: If there's no need to use transactional features why incur the overhead? (albeit minor). It seems you are using atoms to get globally mutable references. What you are doing here is classic map/reduce. Why not get each threaded invocation to return the data rather than set atoms and then 'reduce' the results into a single data structure. btw, this looks like a good case for the reducers library coming in clojure 1.5.0

Comment: Well the transactional features of atoms are being used (appropriately, i think) in the preceding step where the frequency distributions are being generated. It would not be sensible to use map/reduce for that part because it turns out that merging hashmaps all the time makes things slow. Your intuition about using map/reduce at this stage is more sensible; The problem is that memory usage would double during this process. When resetting the atoms, the old frequency distributions can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question on converting the prob distribution.

If you rewrite 'freq-prob' like this:

```
(defn cnv-freq [m]
 (let [t (apply + (vals m))]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [k (/ v t)]) m))))
(defn freq-prob [m]
 (into {} (pmap (fn [[k v]] [k (cnv-freq v)]) m)))
```

You can enable/disable parallel execution by changing 'pmap' to 'map'.